# Place animated footer under other divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, footer

so I wanted an animated footer for my webpage using jquery. There's supposed to be a button which should trigger the animation. I found a nice example for all this, and everything is fine and dandy. Except that the button (including the footer) has this code that makes it stick to the bottom of your web browser, rather than to the bottom of the page. I do [i]not[/i] want it to, like, "scroll" along with the page, I realy want it to be underneath all my other divs. I tried putting it in the div container (which has all my other divs in it as well), but that doesn't seem to work.

Now, (after 2.5 hours of googling) I found out that it might/may/could have something to do with "absolute" positioning in the CSS, so I tried switching some things around such as giving the footer's container a relative position or giving it an "overflow: hidden;" along with the rest a left float but nothing seemed to solve my problem. (I could've done something wrong, not that great with CSS after all :-/)

I hope someone is able/willing to help.

P.S. Here's the example I used:
http://return-true.com/2010/04/jquery-pop-up-footer-version-2/

and here's the code:

Javascript:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        var open = false;
        $('#footerSlideButton').click(function () {
            if(open === false) {
                $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '300px' });
                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
                open = true;
            } else {
                $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
                open = false;
            }
        }); 
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footerPlacement">
    <div id="footerSlideContainer">
        <div id="footerSlideButton"></div>
            <div id="footerSlideContent">
            <div id="footerSlideText">
                <h3>Hey! I'm a Sliding Footer</h3>
                    <p>What's a Sliding Footer? Well I'm a cool little element which can be hidden from view, and revealed when the user wants to see me.</p>
                    <p>What can you use me for? Well look at all this stuff:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Sales information</li>
                        <li>Important updates</li>
                        <li>Unobtrusive about panel</li>
                        <li>Or just a good ol' footer</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>There are obviously many other uses, but these are the few useful ones I can think of.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footerPlacement {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#footerSlideContainer {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 1000px;
}
#footerSlideButton {
    background: url('../images/footer/footerbtn.png') top left no-repeat transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -55px;
    right: 20px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#footerSlideContent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: #251b15;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: none;
    font-family: DejaVuSansBook, Sans-Serif;
}
#footerSlideText {
    padding: 15px 10px 25px 25px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tired changing `#footerSlideContainer {position: fixed;}` to `position:static`??

Comment: oh, now I see your fix. Hold on, lemme see

Comment: Ok, so it puts the footer (as in, completely opened up as if you clicked the button) underneath all the other divs, and the button completely disappeared from the page.

Comment: OK, try adding `height:0px` to `#footerSlideContainer` hope it helps. Basically you will have to play around with the `position`, `margin` and `height` of `#footerSlideContainer`. Installing Firebug for mozilla firefox will also help you tackle the issue.

Comment: Ok, so I set position to relative once more to relative while increasing the margin and height. Position relative does put it to the bottom of the page, but it destroys animation, sort of, because the animation happens below the button, and the button won't move up so it basically happens off-screen. (I noticed it by increasing the margin). Increasing the margin puts it in places I don't want it to be, and changing the height isn't a good idea, cuz it determines the height of the footer, so if I set that to 0, it won't show at all. if I set it to 100, it shows the top 100px of the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change your `#footerPlacement` to include `position:relative`, you can change `#footerSlideContainer` to be `position:absolute` and then your footer will sit below any content above it.

However you will need to make the content have a min-height of around 350px for the footer to work properly and if your content isn't long enough, the footer won't be at the bottom of the browser.

I also added `overflow:hidden` to `#footerSlideContent`.  I have made a fiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/tc6b8/